# Parallel data collections in F#

Tags: dictionary, f#, parallel-processing

Which of list, array or seq are more efficient for parallel processing and can easily implement parallel operations such as `parmap`, `parfilter`, etc?

*EDIT:*
Thanks for the suggestions. `Array.Parallel` looks like a good option. Also checked out `PSeq.fs` and I have got a question about how the `pmap` below work.

```
let pmap f xs =
   seq { for x in xs -> async { return f xs } }
   |> Async.Parallel
   |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Does a new thread get spawned for each element in the sequence? If so, is there a way of breaking the seq into chunks and creating a new task for each chunk to get evaluated in parallel?

I would also like to see if there is any similar `pmap` implementation for list. I found Tomas has a `ParallelList` implementation in his blog post [here](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsparallelops.aspx). But I am not sure whether converting a list to array to perform parallel evaluation does not incur too much overhead and if it can be avoided?

**EDIT:**
Thanks for all your inputs. Tomas answered my original question.

Answering my own question in the first edit:

I tried breaking a big list into chunks then apply async to each sublist.

```
let pmapchunk f xs =
    let chunks = chunk chunksize xs
    seq { for chunk in chunks -> async { return (Seq.map f) chunk } }
    |> Async.Parallel
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
    |> Seq.concat
```

The results: `map`: 15s, `pmap`: 7s, `pmapchunk`: 10s.

Comment: It depends but you almost certainly want `Array.Parallel` and not `async`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a parallel implementation of some array operations in the F# library. In general, working with arrays is probably going to be most efficient if the individual operations take a long time.

- Take a look at the `Array.Parallel` module. It contains functions for creating array (`init`), for performing calculations with elements (`map`) and also `choose` function that can be used to implement filtering.

If you're writing a complex pipeline of operations that are fairly simple, but there is a large number of them, you'll need to use PLINQ, which parallelizes the entire pipe-line as opposed to parallelizing just individual operations (like map).

- Take a look at the `PSeq` module from [F# PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/) for an F# friendly wrapper - it defines `pseq<'T>` type and the usual functions for working with them. This [blog post](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-parallel-plinq.aspx) also contains some useful information.

Comment: thanks. I did come across `Array.Parallel`, `PSeq`, and also `ParallelList` on your blog. The last two do not seem to be included in  the library reference, only `Array.Parallel` does. I've edited the question, please have a look.

Comment: "working with arrays is probably going to be most efficient if the individual operations take a long time"? I'd expect arrays to be relatively faster when the individual operations are quick.

Answer (score 1):

Along with Tomas' suggestion to look at `Array.Parallel`, it's worth noting that arrays (and array-backed collections) will always be the most efficient to traverse (map, iter, ...) because they're stored in contiguous memory.

Answer (score 0):

Realistically, the overhead of switching collection types is tiny compared to the cost of doing an async operation, so the collection type doesn't matter.

Having said that, `List` does tend to mesh more nicely with F# syntax so it may be nicest

Comment: `list` is the worst possible collection type for parallel programming because it is embarrassingly sequential.